# Going through a numpy array with order and mean calculations without a for loop

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression, mean, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to turn this for loop into a numpy function. The `y_mean` function checks for the amount of number stated at the `numbers` variable at once from the `list_` then it prints out the mean for it, so it calculates the mean for `457.334015,424.440002` then for `424.440002,394.795990` and so on until it reaches the end of the `list`. For the `xy_mean` the y is going to be multiplied by the position order of x. So since the first 2 numbers are `457.334015,424.440002` The calculations will be `(1 * 457.334015+ 2 * 424.440002)/number)` and the second and third number will be `(2* 424.440002+ 3* 394.795990)/number`. How could I turn these two functions into numpy form without using a for loop.

Vanilla Form:

```
list_ = [457.334015,424.440002,394.795990,408.903992,398.821014,402.152008,435.790985,423.204987,411.574005,
404.424988,399.519989,377.181000,375.467010,386.944000,383.614990,375.071991,359.511993,328.865997,
320.510010,330.079010,336.187012,352.940002,365.026001,361.562012,362.299011,378.549011,390.414001,
400.869995,394.773010,382.556000]

number = 2
for i in range(len(list_)-number):
    y_mean = sum(list_[i:i+number])/number
    xy_mean = sum([x * (i + 1) for i, x in enumerate(PC_list[i:i+number])])/number
```

Numpy form:

```
list_= np.array([457.334015,424.440002,394.795990,408.903992,398.821014,402.152008,435.790985,423.204987,411.574005,
404.424988,399.519989,377.181000,375.467010,386.944000,383.614990,375.071991,359.511993,328.865997,
320.510010,330.079010,336.187012,352.940002,365.026001,361.562012,362.299011,378.549011,390.414001,
400.869995,394.773010,382.556000])

number = 2
y_mean = list_.mean()
```

Comment: What is `PC_list` here?

Comment: This code isn't clear at all, you are calculating `y_mean` in the loop, where are you using it? Every time it's recalculated, the previous value of `y_mean` gets overwritten. So why are you calculating all that? Same goes for xy_mean as well, did you mean to calculate them and append them to a list instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the OP meant to append the values into a list and that `PC_list` is just another list of the same size that of `list_`, this can be done using `np.convolve`

```
import numpy as np

list_ = np.array([457.334015,424.440002,394.795990,408.903992,398.821014,402.152008,435.790985,423.204987,411.574005,
404.424988,399.519989,377.181000,375.467010,386.944000,383.614990,375.071991,359.511993,328.865997,
320.510010,330.079010,336.187012,352.940002,365.026001,361.562012,362.299011,378.549011,390.414001,
400.869995,394.773010,382.556000])

PC_list = np.random.rand(len(list_))

number = 2
y_mean_list = []
xy_mean_list = []
for i in range(len(list_)-number):
    y_mean = sum(list_[i:i+number])/number
    xy_mean = sum([x * (i + 1) for i, x in enumerate(PC_list[i:i+number])])/number

    y_mean_list.append(y_mean)
    xy_mean_list.append(xy_mean)

ym = (np.convolve(list_, np.ones(shape=(number)), mode='valid')/number)[:-1]
xym = (np.convolve(PC_list, np.arange(number, 0, -1), mode='valid')/number)[:-1]

print(np.allclose(xym, xy_mean_list))
print(np.allclose(ym, y_mean_list))
```